# chromebook 14 touchpad not working with newly installed ubuntu 14.10

Tags: touchpad, 14.10, chromebook

I just got a new hp chromebook 14, installed ubuntu 14.10 through chrubuntu and unfortunately, although everything else seems to be ok, the touchpad does not work at all. I am new to ubuntu/linux etc, and really have no idea how to solve the problem, can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to kernel 3.18. Should fix your touchpad.

Instructions here: http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/12/install-linux-kernel-3-18-ubuntu/

Ctrl+Alt+T will open a terminal window so that you can run all the commands in that article.